# How to get an id from url and use it in another controller create view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to .net C# but I wound to get the id I put in the url. In my project details I put a link to create member. but now the users have to select that previous project Id with an combo box. I wound this to be auto.

In my project/details

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add member", "Create", "ProjectMember", new { id=Model.ProjectID }, null)
```

Result =>
ProjectMember/Create/1 (=id from project)

I want to get the ID so wen I create a new projectmember the user does not have to select the id from project from the dropbox that was auto generated in the create view

I looked some things up and came with this answer

```
<%=Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]%>
```

but when i post this in the It came out the view exactly like <%=Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]%>

Comment: please explain properly what you want exactly..

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC passing an ID in an ActionLink to the controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316889/asp-net-mvc-passing-an-id-in-an-actionlink-to-the-controller)

Comment: I want to get the ID so wen I create a new projectmember the user does not have to select the id from project

Answer (score 0):

you can pass id in ActionLink Like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add member", "Create", "ProjectMember", new { id=Model.ProjectID }, null)
```

for more information . see this link [**ActionLink**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: thank you for getting me the correct syntax but it is not wat I'm looking for

Comment: @user257696: then what are you looking for . can you explain ?
as you explain above, you can get the id in Action Method .you don't need to select from project.

Comment: I want to get the ID so wen I create a new projectmember the user does not have to select the id from project from the dropbox that was auto generated in the create view